# Featureclass from dev env to test env

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, feature-class

I am new to GIS.
I have created a geodatabase. And inside this geodatabase i have created a feature class, i created a mxd file to publish feature service. Since this was all in development environment and i want to create same feature class in a geodatabase in test environment and somehow use mxd file too if possible.

I have to do this process just once in each environment.

I am hoping that instead of creating geodatabse and featureclass from scratch in test environment again, i can somehow copy geodatabase with featureclass from my development environment and maybe able to copy it in test environment.

I am using Oracle for geodatabase, ArcMap and ArcCatalog to create feature service, mxd files.

I have to do this process just once in each environment.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange. As with many things in GIS, there are a lot of possible ways to move data between databases. It would help if you could edit your question to include more information. Ex: What software are you using, what types of databases are involved, is this a one-time deal or will this be a regular workflow need that you are wanting help automating, do you have special needs like preserving database manged IDs (GlobalID, OID,...) or are multiple datasets involved (ex: relationship class). If basic software help doesn't help, we need more details to help you.

Comment: @Jphn, Thank you so much for your comment. I have edited my question and tried to be more clear. Please let me know if i am missing any information that might make it easy to answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that when you mention a feature service, near the end of your question, this is just something you want to do after copying your geodatabase feature classes.

To copy a feature class as a one off in ArcCatalog you should be able to right-click on it and choose Copy, then Paste it onto the desired geodatabase or feature dataset.